# Where to add code for a gridview hyperlink to delete a row by user's click?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEditAdsPic">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="ترتیب عکس" FieldName="show_order" VisibleIndex="3">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="شماره آگهی" FieldName="adver_no" VisibleIndex="0">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn Caption="delete add" FieldName="show_order" VisibleIndex="4" >
                <PropertiesHyperLinkEdit Text="حذف">
                </PropertiesHyperLinkEdit>
            </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>


            <dx:GridViewDataImageColumn Caption="عکس" FieldName="pic_path" VisibleIndex="2">

                <PropertiesImage ImageHeight="100px" ImageWidth="150px">
                </PropertiesImage>
            </dx:GridViewDataImageColumn>
        </Columns>
        <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" />
        <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" AllowEdit="False" AllowInsert="False" />
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

I have a DevExpress gridview for which I have added a column for deleting rows. Where should I add the code for the event of a user clicking the delete. I double clicked on the link to show to method but it doesn't.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the code

```
<PropertiesHyperLinkEdit Text="حذف">
</PropertiesHyperLinkEdit>
```

And Write

```
<PropertiesHyperLinkEdit Text="حذف" ClientSideEvents-Click="function(s,e){s.DeleteRow(e.visibleIndex);}"></PropertiesHyperLinkEdit>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions related to the same.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I forgot to check this. I'll test your code and will surely accept it if it works.